# How to view only the differences in WinMerge

Tags: windows-7, winmerge

I have two text documents with 1000 lines each and there are (let's say) 50 lines that are highlighted as different. Is there a way to view/extract only those lines that differ, either with a filter or perhaps a way to sort to get the differences at the top?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [WinMerge 2011](http://www.geocities.co.jp/SiliconValley-SanJose/8165/unofficial_winmerge_nightly_builds.html) fork instead which [has this feature](http://forums.winmerge.org/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=92&start=10#p1393):

[image: 1]

Comment: Any way to enable this feature by default?

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg: There might be, but I'm not sure. The WinMerge forum (or even the specific thread I linked to above) would be the best place to ask. If you find out how to do it, don't forget to leave a comment or add it above as well to help others.

Comment: The problem for me came that I somehow enabled the feature by accident, and didn't know why I was only seeing the differences.  Then stumbled onto this superuser.  So I was able to figure out how to undo it.

Answer (score 7):

For today, with version 2.16.16.0 x64 of WinMerge you can show only rows that differ by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> keyboard shortcut which is the same as menu: `View` => `Context difference` => `Switch all rows`.