# Why is WinMerge hiding most of my file, even after I copy all the changes over from one side or the other?

Tags: winmerge

It's really confusing - why are only lines 134-148 visible? Is there some option I accidentally enabled that hides code that has not changed? I tried to update to the latest version (2.16.8.0) but the about box still says 2.16.4.0 even after running the installer and restarting the app... What's really weird is before I copy the code over, the middle pane is completely blank, even though I have the option to perform an initial merge on startup enabled, and pressing F5 to refresh does not help... And I used to be able to actually save the file properly after doing this, but now the merge process actually *deletes* all the code that is hidden! Good thing I checked before creating my pull request! Could this have something to do with character encodings? I noticed the previous version of the file was Unicode (UTF-8) while the merged version is Western European (Windows)... Well, I had three files that broke in this way out of seven conflicts that I merged, and one of them had the character encoding issue...

[image]

Comment: And now restarting WinMerge one more time, it displays the correct version number... Wonder why it wasn't before? Some sort of background process? But why would it reset this time and not earlier? This time I started it manually rather than via Visual Studio's merge button; maybe I have two installations of it somehow?

Comment: I have been using WinMerge for some time (2.16.4 until just now and just updated to 2.16.8  If I use the WinMerge (GUI) compare screen from Context or WinMerge, it starts at the top. WinMerge is highly context oriented, so maybe uninstall it, restart and install it again. Also use the 64-bit version.

Comment: Looks like when I updated to 2.16.8, I accidentally installed the 32-bit version, which explains why Visual Studio couldn't find it. I uninstalled them both and installed the 64-bit version of 2.16.8. Which seems to have fixed the problem - thanks!

Comment: Would you give some credit for the answer I posted here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the 64 bit version of 2.16.8 seems to have fixed my problem; I accidentally installed the 32 bit version by mistake earlier, which explains why Visual Studio was still using 2.16.4.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I think the setting in winmerge to control that is mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/901463/how-to-view-only-the-differences-in-winmerge)